# Curl, авторизация с переадресацией

Tags: php, curl, авторизация

Нашел информацию что, curl не следует переадресации, если это мета теги или JS. Подскажите пожалуйста, как тогда можно реализовать, что бы после авторизации адресовало на необходимую страницу?

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3');

$post = "email=support@some.com&pass=MyPass&&MM_logn=logn";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somesite/user/logpass.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
echo $html;
```

Comment: Сохраняете куки после подключения, а потом обращаетесь к нужной странице используя куки

Comment: `chrome --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222`. Прелесть в том что работает и без иксов, я поднимал на сервере и получал полноценную браузерную обработку, с API доступом